# Is my implementation of one-time password safe enough?

Tags: security, http, authentication, web, one-time-password

I want to implement a login mechanism for authenticating the administrator of my web app. But since I am not using ssl I cannot rely on user sending his password through an html form.

So I thought about using one-time password (I actually didn't know about this thing, I ended up reinventing the concept and eventually found out such a thing already existed)

All I want is your opinion on how safe my implementation is:

1) Client requests a random and unique hash. The server generates that hash, stores it in a session variable and returns the hash to the client.

2) From that hash the client derives a password using a custom algorithm that is known only by him and the server. That password is sent back to server.

3) Server does the same and check to see if passwords match, if they do the user is authenticated.

Can this be cracked at all?

Answer (score 5):

*"custom algorithm that is known only by him and the server"*. This is broken by design, since you are relying solely on the algorithm being secret.

It won't be a secret anymore as soon as you distribute the implementation (e.g. as client side JavaScript), let alone any intrinsic weakness in the protocol.

My 2cents: unless you are a crypto expert, never roll out your own solution. Stick with public, sound and proven protocols and only use reputable implementations.

Comment: but you see, I don't have to and am not going to "distribute" the implementation. The only parts that have the implementation is the server and a single client.

Comment: It won't change much... The bottom line is that _security through obscurity_ has been proven ineffective since a long time ago. Cryptanalytic techniques could be used to discover the algorithm. If the connection is not securely encrypted, anyone can observe what you exchange with the server and potentially "steal" your identity as a last resort.

Comment: The hashes being exchanged are useless to any observer, I think that's clear. Now I don't see how any technique could discover all the implementation of a custom hash generator (it could be anything! e.g. I could do md5 + sha1 + md5 7204134 times using a different salt in each iteration). Only if the attacker is able to make trillions of tests, but of course I will not allow so many attempts. If I allow only one attempt per minute for instance it will be nearly impossible for any one to crack me. Maybe by 2099 the poor chap will get into something.

Comment: Additionally, one might guess what operations have been applied by observing the timing of requests and responses. I suggest learning about Diffie-Hellman key agreement and Socialist Millionaire protocol for something really sound. Anyway, you will end up reimplementing most of what TLS/SSL already offers.

Comment: Remember Kerckhoff's Principle: "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge" (or, as Claude Shannon put it, "the enemy knows the system"). Also, hash algorithms are NOT meant to be combined like that; it does NOT make them more secure, and can in fact make it easier to break. I cannot stress enough how important it is that software developers understand why you should never invent your own crypto. Go ask around in [the Information Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/); those guys really know their stuff.